# how to hide windows 7 switch user button in vc++ CredentialProvider sample

Tags: c++, windows-7, sdk, authentication, credentials

[image: Credential provider screenshot]

1. I have provided a screenshot of my
   `CredentialProvider` window. In this
   window everything is fine now but i
   don't want to show `Switch User`
   button to the user. How i can do
   this. I am just editing Win-7 SDK
   sample for `CredentialProvider`
   (C++). Anyone can help me, or any
   link for code help.
2. One more thing I want to ask is by default, the username text box displaying `EditText` in grey color. How i could change it to `Username` text. I can set text in `SHStrDupW(L"", &_rgFieldStrings[SFI_EDIT_TEXT]);` code but its not setting in background text. is there any hack for this.

Thanks SO members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly prevent the Switch User button from appearing; if the conditions are present that cause it to appear, then it's going to appear.  What you can do however: prevent the conditions that cause it to appear.

That button appears either when a tile is in the selected state and 1.) your credential provider is enumerating tiles other than the one that is selected, or 2.) other credential providers are enumerating tiles.

The first condition is easy to prevent:  In GetCredentialCount(), always report that you will enumerate only one credential.  (This means of course that you must structure the tile to handle all users.)

To prevent the second condition, you will have to implement a credential provider filter.  (Search for the "ICredentialProviderFilter" interface if you don't know what that is.)

Good luck.

Comment: HI i t searched alot for `ICredentialProviderFilter` implementation but couldn't find any good example. can you help me.

Comment: It's been a few years since this was posted, but if anyone else ends up reading this looking for help, I found [this example](https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-windows-auth/tree/master/yubiprovider/YubiKeyWrapExistingCredentialProvider) very helpful. See CProviderFilter.h and CProviderFilter.cpp.

Note: with the release of windows 8, `CLSID_PasswordCredentialProvider` now refers to specifically the Windows 8 credential provider. If you want to filter out the Windows 7 default as well, you should also filter out `CLSID_V1PasswordCredentialProvider`

Answer (score 3):

To answer question 2:

The username text box is displaying EditText in grey color. You can change it to Username text. You set text using

```
SHStrDupW(L"", &_rgFieldStrings[SFI_EDIT_TEXT]);
```

Have a look at *common.h*, there you'll find

```
CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_FIELD_DESCRIPTOR s_rgCredProvFieldDescriptors[] =  { SFI_EDIT_TEXT, CPFT_EDIT_TEXT, L"Edit Text" }
```

If you change this *Edit Text* to UserName then it will show in your Text Box.